# Steam Install Error on 14.04 Ubuntu 64bit

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, steam

I have tried some of the solutions posted elsewhere in the support forum, one seemed like it worked but after a steam update i found myself back at square one  I am a new Linux user and am already at a learning curve :)  Thanks for any help

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3)
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
Press return to continue:
```

Answer (score 35):

This is what actually works for 14.04:
`sudo apt-get install libc6:i386`
`sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty:i386`

Proof:
[image: An image of steam working after successful installation]
Hope this helps others.

Comment: worked for me as well+

Comment: great :) suggestions to make this answer better are welcomed

Comment: That didn't work for me on Ubuntu 14.04.3.     :-(

Comment: hello Rafael, I keep getting upvotes so I think this post is actually helping others, but I still wonder if you had any luck fixing this issue :) I saw your profile and noticed you're a teacher, teachers get special treatment in my book, let me know if I can help you

Answer (score 29):

Workaround:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-utopic:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386
```

The command is a bit different if you are running Ubuntu 14.04.3 or greater with the Hardware Enablement Stack (kernel 3.19):

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid:i386
```

Comment: Perfect, worked like a charm!

Comment: The command is a bit different if you are running Ubuntu 14.04.3 with the Hardware Enablement Stack (kernel 3.19):
`sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid:i386`

Comment: this worked for me (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x86_64: uname -a → 3.16.0-50-generic #67~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 2 22:07:51 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux )

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a bug. I have already reported this issue on Bugs Launchpad and you can follow it using these two bug-tracker links.

- [bug 1424263](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1424263)
- [bug 1424265](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1424265)

You can fix it manually but it is to complicated. Ubuntu devs will fix it soon so I advise you just wait for updates.

Comment: You might want to flag this next time as a bug

Comment: It's still not fixed.   Perhaps next year...

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 14.04.3 try this workaround:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid:i386
```

Comment: I've been looking everywhere for this! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found this worked for me perfectly.

```
sudo apt-get install steam -y
```