# Missing Steam Packages

Tags: package-management, steam, libraries

In Ubuntu 14.04, when I try to install steam via .deb file, it shows:

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386, libc6:i386
```

Then it asks for my password. I input my password, the terminal loads, and then says this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5)
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages."
```

The packages don't seem to want to install. Any input?

I am an Ubuntu novice. Please be specific with commands.

Comment: could you try installing those required package? run `sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesa:i386 libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7` . then run `sudo apt-get install  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libc6:i386`.

Comment: If you use the graphical package manager, doesn't add the required packages automatically?

Comment: I tried the 'sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesa:i386 libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7' and 'sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libc6:i386' but they give me errors, just like the one at the end of the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Original answer from "[Steam Install Error on 14.04 Ubuntu 64bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588024/steam-install-error-on-14-04-ubuntu-64bit)"

Try this :

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 

sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty:i386
```

Then relaunch Steam