# Error installing dependencies!

Tags: 14.04, package-management, software-installation, mesa

I am having issues installing dependencies for the leapmotion driver on the Ubuntu 14.04. I tried several suggestions but nothing worked. My initial question was regarding how to ignore the dependencies but I was advised not to do that. So, I tried installing the dependencies again but I am still running into the same issues.

Here is the image of my terminal!

[image]

Comment: Start from the beginning. What is your problem, and what are you trying to do to solve it? [Edit] your question, and update it with more information.

Comment: I wondered if you had read the support page from Leap Motion https://support.leapmotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/223782608-Linux-Installation

Comment: and if one googles one gets https://askubuntu.com/questions/588024/steam-install-error-on-14-04-ubuntu-64bit from this forum

Comment: @pdc yeah, i tried  the leapMotion forums but all i ultimately got was to ignore the dependencies but i am trying to ignore that if at all possible

Comment: @pdc   i already tried those options, but thanks for spending the time and trying to help me find a solution.

Comment: You will break your system using the `xenial` repository .

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: @GAD3R: The mesa packages from Xenial were back-ported to Trusty with one of the LTS upgrades and appear in the official repositories for Trusty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a Trusty installation with a graphics stack back-ported from Xenial (as is the case in all fully updated Trusty LTS installation) you need to install the backported versions of the packages:

```
sudo apt install -f libgl1-mesa-{dri,glx}-lts-xenial
```