# Cannot install steam on my Chromebook

Tags: dependencies, steam, chromebook

I don't know much about how Linux works, I just wanted to download steam on my Chromebook, however, whenever I type in the commands to download it, I instead get an error.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 steam:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I don't know what this means and I don't know what to do. A couple months ago I used the same commands to download steam, and it successfully installed, I later uninstalled it and now am unable to reinstall it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Steam Install Error on 14.04 Ubuntu 64bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588024/steam-install-error-on-14-04-ubuntu-64bit)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 for "penguin" container. However, in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` I had `cros.list` and `cros-gpu.list`, there were some Debian sources, which I commented out (using '#')

```
cat cros.list 
#deb https://storage.googleapis.com/cros-packages/84 stretch main

cat cros-gpu.list 
#deb https://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
#deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://apt.llvm.org/stretch/ llvm-toolchain-stretch-7 main
```

Then I did:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install steam
```

and all "libgl1-mesa*" stuff was resolved and installed, no dependencies issues.

Answer (score 0):

Following https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-steam-with-steam-play-on-debian-10-buster worked for me on Pixel Slate:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian-nonfree.list >/dev/null << EOF
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main non-free contrib
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main non-free contrib

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free
EOF

sudo apt update
sudo apt install steam
```